# Parker Solar Probe Launch - Burning Flame

Tags: rockets, launch-site, launchpad

When watching the live launch of the NASA Parker Solar Probe, I noticed that there was a burning flame near the launch site (bottom left in the image)

[image: Burning flame bottom left]

My intuition tells me that it's hydrogen that's burning, but still, what is the purpose of this flame, and why is it so close to the rocket?